# Updates to multiple columns in table 1 that don't match in table 2. i don't want to update if it matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

here are the 2 tables.

```
table 1
id  acct    firstname   lastname
1   11  dave    smith
2   21  john    james
3   32  mike    jones
4   43  steve   alan


table 2
1   11  dave    simpson
2   21  karan   james
3   35  mike    jones
4   42  steve   lynn
```

output I would like to see only what was changed(and be able to update only if mismatched), not sure if this is even possible

````
id  acct    firstname   lastname
1                       simpson
2           karan
3   35  
4   42                  lynn```


        
    update #table1
        set acct= t.acct
        , firstname = t.firstname
        , lastname = t.lastname
        -- select *
        from #table2 t
        inner join #table1 a 
            on a.id = t.ID
        where not ((a.acct = case when a.acct != t.acct  then t.acct  else a.acct  end and
                    a.firstname = case when a.firstname != t.firstname then t.firstname else a.firstname end and
                    a.lastname = case when a.lastname!= t.lastname then t.lastname else a.lastname end
                ))
````

Comment: FWIW ... The `where` clause looks a bit odd. Using a CASE to compare the same values inside and outside the CASE don't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to "erase" the data in table1 that is the same in table2.

```
update table1
    set acct = (case when table2.acct = table1.acct then null else table2.act end),
        firstname = (case when table2.firstname = table1.firstname then null else table2.firstname end),
        lastname = (case when table2.lastname = table1.lastname then null else table2.lastname end)        
    from table2
    where table1.id = table2.id;
```

You can express this more succinctly using `NULLIF()`:

```
update table1
    set acct = nullif(table2.acct, table1.acct),
        firstname = nullif(table2.firstname, table1.firstname),
        lastname = nullif(able2.lastname, table1.lastname)        
    from table2
    where table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use and `OUTPUT` clause ....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
update #table1
    set acct= t.acct
    , firstname = t.firstname
    , lastname = t.lastname
output
    inserted.ID,  

    deleted.acct,  
    inserted.acct,  

    deleted.firstname,  
    inserted.firstname,  

    deleted.lastname,  
    inserted.lastname
    -- select *
    from #table2 t
    inner join #table1 a 
        on a.id = t.ID
    where not ((a.acct = case when a.acct != t.acct  then t.acct  else a.acct  end and
                a.firstname = case when a.firstname != t.firstname then t.firstname else a.firstname end and
                a.lastname = case when a.lastname!= t.lastname then t.lastname else a.lastname end
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your post is going in the direction of manual change tracking, there's the possibility to update your target table with the changes in one single [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement. That could look like this:

```
merge into table2 t2 using (select * from table1) t1
on t2.id = t1.id
when not matched by target 
then
insert (id, acct, firstname, lastname) values (t1.id, t1.acct, t1.firstname, t1.lastname)

when matched 
and (t2.acct != t1.acct or (t2.acct is null and t1.acct is not null) or (t2.acct is not null and t1.acct is null)
or t2.firstname != t1.firstname or (t2.firstname is null and t1.firstname is not null) or (t2.firstname is not null and t1.firstname is null)
or t2.lastname != t1.lastname or (t2.lastname is null and t1.lastname is not null) or (t2.lastname is not null and t1.lastname is null)) 

then
update set t2.acct = t1.acct, t2.firstname = t1.firstname, t2.lastname = t1.lastname, t2.lastupdated = sysdatetime() --last column keeps the time of the last change registered

when not matched by source 
then
update set t2.lastupdated = sysdatetime(), t2.deleted = 1 --assuming there's a deleted column that you want to update
```

This statements joins table1 and table2 using the `id` column. If the id exists in one table and not the other, then it allows you to update or insert data. You can also have additional conditions (like checking for differences on the other columns) in order to adapt your data with more attributes like a lastupdated or deleted information.